# Reusing slot numbers in Linux software RAID arrays

Tags: linux, software-raid

When a hard disk drive in one of my Linux machines failed, I took the opportunity to migrate from RAID5 to a 6-disk software RAID6 array.

At the time of the migration I did not have all 6 drives - more specifically the fourth and fifth (slots 3 and 4) drives were already in use in the originating array, so I created the RAID6 array with a couple of `missing` devices. I now need to add those drives in those empty slots. Using `mdadm --add` *does* result in a proper RAID6 configuration, with one glitch - the new drives are placed in *new* slots, which results in this `/proc/mdstat` snippet:

```
...
md0 : active raid6 sde1[7] sdd1[6] sda1[0] sdf1[5] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      25185536 blocks super 1.0 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
...
```

`mdadm -E` verifies that the actual slot numbers in the device superblocks are correct, yet the numbers shown in `/proc/mdstat` are still *weird*.

I would like to fix this glitch, both to satisfy my inner perfectionist and to avoid any potential sources of future confusion in a crisis. Is there a way to specify which slot a new device should occupy in a RAID array?

**UPDATE:**

I have verified that the slot number persists in the component device superblock. For the version 1.0 superblocks that I am using that would be the `dev_number` field as defined in `include/linux/raid/md_p.h` of the Linux kernel source. I am now considering direct modification of said field to change the slot number - I don't suppose there is some standard way to manipulate the RAID superblock?

**UPDATE 2:**

To modify the slot assignments in the device superblock I would need to do the following:

1. Modify `dev_number`
2. Modify the `dev_roles` array to mark the old slot as empty and place the proper role at the new slot
3. Re-compute the superblock checksum

(1) and (2) are relatively simple and can be automated via a script or small program. (3) started to push things a little - I would have to rip the superblock checksum code from the `md` driver, modify it to work with a userspace program and hope for the best.

Rather than spend my time debugging a C application and risk killing my arrays with a bug, I decided to try to trick `md`/`mdadm` into doing my work for me, as mentioned in my answer. This seems to have worked, although it may still have a degree of risk...

Comment: Do the slot numbers persist after completely stopping and recreating md0 (or simply, a clean boot)?

Comment: If by *recreating* you mean `mdadm --create` then I would guess not, since that means rebuilding the array from raw data. If you mean `mdadm --assemble` then yes, the numbers seem to persist through an `mdadm --stop`/`mdadm --assemble` cycle...

Comment: Does this behavior bring you any troubles? It seems harmless to me

Comment: @KamilŠrot: The array *is* fully functional, so I suppose it could be deemed harmless. That said, it is counter-intuitive and it lays to waste all my efforts to keep a correspondence between disk bays and RAID slots so that drives can be easily replaced. I would now have to keep a file with drive serial numbers and RAID slots, to avoid confusion...

Comment: @thkala makes definitely sense - I would suggest to get some better identification of the drive. eg. find out the PCI id of each bay (what does `ls /dev/disk/by-path` say?). I also noted somewhere "Location" property for hard drive, however I don't remember if it can solve your problem...

Comment: @KamilŠrot: PCI layouts and SATA port arrangements may change dynamically... matching the RAID slot, which describes *what* the drive contains, rather than *where* it is to its physical location sort of makes more sense to me.

Comment: @KamilŠrot: I think I remember reading that with some enterprise-grade enclosures Linux was able to determine the physical location of the drive in question. Unfortunately, I am dealing with consumer-grade equipment, so I doubt that ability exists here. Anyway, I found a way to do what I wanted to without going to too extreme measures. Thank you for your help!